# require client certificates in IIS without requiring SSL

Tags: security, iis, ssl, authentication, ssl-certificate

In IIS 7, I've created an https binding for a site, and I'd like to require client certificates for https and still keep my http endpoint.

That is to say, I'd like to require client certificates for my https endpoint without requiring SSL across the board and disallowing access to my http endpoint (via "require SSL" in SSL Settings). Is this possible?

Comment: Define "endpoint"? Each site has it's own SSL settings.

Comment: so, for my site i've created two bindings, one for http and one for https. now, for the https binding, i'd like to require client certificates without losing the http binding.

Comment: OK, understood. I though you were referring to two different web sites.